# Freestyle SVG Export with Stereoscopy

Tags: export, camera, freestyle, svg, saving

I have a scene set up with multiple cameras and I have it working so that I can get multiple raster images and save them. However With Freestyle SVG enabled it saves all of the svg images on top of one another in a single image with the frame number.
I want each of the cameras to export an svg image in the same way as the rasters. Is this possible?